# Why can I use True or False as indexes of a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this example:

```
a = [-10,10][True]
b = [-10,10][False]
print(a,b)# "10 -10"
```

Comment: I remember being appalled by this the first time I saw this.  But I've gotten used to it.  It also means that rather than writing: `if some_boolean: count += 1`, you can instead write `count += some_boolean`.  Your opinion of this may vary.

Comment: It's also possible to do things such as `some_var=['some_action','some_other_action'][function_that_returns_a_bool()]`, which is more readable, omce you're used to it, than the equivalent if/else boilerplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `bool` is a subclass of `int` that's why `True` acts like 1 and `False` like 0

Comment: As stated in the dupe.